# Wordpress & advanced custom fields

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I'm trying to include a few custom fields I've created in my functions.php file so they're native to the theme I'm working on. However they're not showing up on the edit screens of the posts I've set them to.

I've included the acf plugin in my theme by using this code in my functions.php:  include_once('advanced-custom-fields/acf.php');

I also exported the fields to php and copy and pasted the code in the functions.php of my theme. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: post your question with some code you have tried.

Comment: I'm just using the code Advanced Custom Fields returns when I click export..

Comment: Have you established a rule to have ACF add the custom fields to the post? The rule will place your field on the post/page that you want them to render on so they can be filled out.

Answer (score 0):

The code generated by act itself won't get you far.
Try using

```
the_field('the-field-you-wish-to-display');
```

inside the loop to display whatever fields you want.

Answer (score 0):

Just use ->

```
`<?php the_field($field_name, $post_id); ?>`
```

where $post_id is optional.

Or use ->

```
<?php $field = get_field($field_name, $post_id, $format_value); ?>
```

which is more functional. You can echo a value later with it.